# Are subspaces of paracompact spaces normal?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms, paracompactness

Are all subspaces of a [paracompact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space) space normal?

This is what I think about this question...
First a paracompact Hausdorff space turns out to be Normal, second the paracompact property  is not hereditary, meaning any subspace need to be closed+Hausdorff to be normal. So I think the answer is no, but I have to find a counter-example.

Am I right about this and what counter-example do we have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every compact space is paracompact. Let $X$ be the one-point compactification of a countably infinite discrete space $X_0$, and let $Y$ be the one-point compactification of an uncountable discrete space $Y_0$. Let $p$ be the non-isolated point of $X$ and $q$ the non-isolated point of $Y$. Then $X\times Y$ is compact, so it’s paracompact. However, the subspace

$$Z=(X\times Y)\setminus\{\langle p,q\rangle\}$$

is not even normal, so it’s certainly not paracompact. Specifically, the closed sets $H=X_0\times\{q\}$ and $K=\{p\}\times Y_0$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets.

To see this, suppose that $U$ is an open nbhd of $H$. For each $x\in X_0$ there is a finite $F_x\subseteq Y_0$ such that $\langle x,q\rangle\in\{x\}\times(Y\setminus F_x)\subseteq U$. Let $F=\bigcup_{x\in X_0}F_x$; then $F$ is countable, so there is a $y\in Y_0\setminus F$. But then $X\times\{y\}\subseteq U$, so no open nbhd of $\langle p,y\rangle$ is disjoint from $U$, and therefore no open nbhd of $K$ is disjoint from $U$.

Comment: your answer was clear,just wonder if we add the closeness to our subspace in this case we will get the paracompact for free, but are still we need Hausdorff to be normal ( the subspace ).

Comment: @Birkary: Yes, if you restrict yourself to closed subspaces you get paracompactness for free, but you don’t necessarily get normality unless the subspace is Hausdorff.

Comment: thanks,this was very helpful. I will make sure to understand the answer you give.

Comment: @Birkary: You’re welcome.

Comment: More generally, any non-normal space has a compactification $id_X:X\to cX.$ So $X$ is a non-paracompact sub-space of the compact Hausdorff  space $cX.$....We can also say this if $X$ is normal but not paracompact. For example if $X$ is $\omega_1$ with the $\in$-order topology, and $cX=\omega_1+1$.